# I can't display my sorted array with Javascript in HTML (innerHTML)

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I sorted an array of integers and I tried to display it with HTML but I don't know how to do it.

I already tried to print the elements without using the function display

```js
var array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 5];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[i] > array[j]) {
      var temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
  }
}

function display(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
    document.getElementById("visualization").innerHTML = array;
  }
}

window.document.getElementById("visualization").innerHTML = display(array);
```

```html
<p id="visualization"></p>
```

Expected result: 2,3,4,5,8
Actual result: undefined

*When I use Chrome console it just works fine! There's nothing wrong about the sorting code.*

Comment: `display` function doesn't return anything, hence `undefined`, i.e. the result of the function call, is shown on the page.

Comment: And you're assigning the innerHTML in the display function multiple times too.

Comment: Why do you need a custom sorting algorithm? Array.prototype.sort does it all and does it better

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is that execution of `display` function returns nothing, so it implicitly returns `undefined` and you are setting this result (`undefined`) into `innerHTML` of that element. One of the possible solutions would be returning string from `display` function, or prepare string of all values inside that function, set `innerHTML` to that string, return nothing and then only call `display` function (below is an example)

You need to create string for `innerHTML`

```js
var array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 5];

array.sort((a,b) => a < b ? -1 : (a == b ? 0 : 1));

function display(array){
    var html = "";
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        console.log(array[i]);
        html += `<p>${array[i]} </p>`;
    }
    document.getElementById("visualization").innerHTML = html;

}

display(array)
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="visualization"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code a bit,

Take a look at the jsFiddle,

you could just use the array sort method,

You are trying to innerHTML a function that has no return value.
Instead try returning a string,
Or use string join method

```js
 var array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 5];

array.sort()

document.getElementById("visualization").innerHTML = array.join(",")
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="visualization"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mje21Lwv/

```
  var array = [4, 2, 8, 3, 5];

  array.sort()

  document.getElementById("visualization").innerHTML = array.join(",")
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I tried to sort it without using the sort function. By the way I returned my array and everything worked. Thank you very much